# PHP - Understanding self::__construct() call

Tags: php, wordpress

I came across a Wordpress widget that looked something like this

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

   function my_widget() { return self::__construct(); }

   function __construct() {
     // Some code here
     ...
   }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', "return register_widget('my_widget');" ) );
```

The __construct() will be invoked when an object is created. What help or functionality does the my_widget() function provide? Is it really needed? Any significance of that function having the same name as the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just provide the backward compatibility for PHP4, nothing else.

For PHP4, `my_widget` is the constructor method, so it have to call `__construct` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like compability with PHP4... 
I would say that this code is weird.